# How to print integer in a for-loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, how do I print integer one below the other:

```
a1 = "Great"
a2 = 100
for all in a1:
    print(all)
```

Output:

```
G
r
e
a
t
```

Question: How do I write `for`/`print` statement for the variable `a2`, so that my output will be:

```
1
0
0
```

?

Comment: `for all in str(a2): print(all)`

Comment: `int` objects aren't iterable, so convert it into some appropriate iterable object, e.g. a `str`

Comment: The reason why your code fails when you try to iterate through an integer is because integers are unique numbers. Python sees 100, not 1 and 0 and 0. Whereas strings are sequences of characters.

Comment: @DarknessPlusPlus: nice explanation! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `a2`, an int into something that is iterable. One way you could do this is by converting `a2` into a string:

```
a2 = 100
for str_digit in str(a2): # if a2 is negative use str(a2)[1:] to not print '-' sign
    print(str_digit)
```

And another way could be by extracting the individual digits (still as ints) from `a2` into a list (or another iterable):

```
def get_digits(num):
    num = abs(num)
    digits = []
    while num != 0:
        digits.append(num % 10)
        num //= 10
    return digits

a2 = 100
for str_digit in get_digits(a2):
    print(str_digit)
```

**Output:**

```
1
0
0
```

Answer (score 2):

An object of type `int` is not iterable. So force it to be iterable by making it a `string`.

```
x = 1337
for num in str(x):
  print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

> To get letters of a word or elements of a number by a for loop you need a string

> a = 100 is an integer so you need to convert it to a **string** like below :

```
a=str(100)
for i in a:
    print(i)
```